# Overriding $exceptionhander in AnguarJS to redirect exception onto custom modal using TB3+

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scope

I am trying to override $exceptionHandler with factory by help of some of the answers on this site. My target is to redirect every exception that occurs in angular whether it is internal or custom it should be displayed onto a custom MODAL window (using twitter bootstrap3).

```
myApp.factory('$exceptionHandler',function ($injector) {
return function (exception, cause) {
  var items = {"err": exception.message};
    var modal1 = $injector.get('$modal');
  var myModal = modal1.open({
          templateUrl: 'app/js/other/templates/modal.html',
          controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
          resolve: {
            values: function(){
                return items;
                }
          }
        });
    myModal.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        }, function () {
            alert('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });


};  

});
```

I have to use $injector as to avoid a circular dependency. 
the controller is given below

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl =function ($scope,$modalInstance,items) {
$scope.msg.items = items;
}]);
```

Now the problem arises here that my modal gets opened correctly but the error that i pass does not gets rendered.
since implementing $exceptionHandler as factory how to provide a scope for the custom modal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [$rootScope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope). It can be injected into factory and will be available everywhere.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but unfortunately that did not work in my case as i am using $translate service for localization and this is messing up with $translate showing a circular dependency.
    Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope <- $translate